# Delete data from child tables before deleting from the parent table in SQL

Tags: sql, mysql

I would like to delete the records from a child table that are associated with an ID from the parent table before deleting the respective parent table record using single query.

I am familiar with the concept of **CASCADE**, but it doesn't apply in my case. This is because I have some records in the child table that reference IDs from the parent table. However, in reality, these records do not exist in the parent table. As a result, I'm currently unable to establish a foreign key relationship and utilize CASCADE.

Running individual queries for each child table is one potential solution. However, repeatedly passing the ID for each table and executing queries separately can be impractical. Is there a method to efficiently delete all associated records using a single query?

[Here is the table structure: "Spills" serves as the parent table, while all others function as its child tables.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OwY1I.png)

```
delete t1, t2
from table1 t1
left join table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.table1_id
where t1.id in (?, ?, ?, ?);
```

This solution isn't effective for my situation due to the presence of nested child tables. Could you guide me on how to perform joins with these nested child tables?